# how to login and download file using perforce command line

Tags: command-line, perforce

I have to download a file daily from perforce depot.

Presently I do it manually by selecting that file and using "Get latest version" option.

I want to write a script which I will schedule in my windows task schedular to get the file daily.

Please help me/guide me how to do this task automatically.

I am using p4v client software in windows XP operating system.

Answer (score 12):

Using P4V will make it hard to automate. I suggest you use the command-line client, p4.exe, instead. If there's only one file that you need the contents of you could simply use "p4 print" and avoid the need for creating a workspace (client) spec, e.g:

`p4 print -o <local filename> //depot/path/to/file`

Note that the above command requires you to be already logged on to the Perforce server. There's at least two ways around this:

1) Specify the username and password on the [command-line](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.gopts.html#1040647) (not really recommended for security reasons):

`p4 -u myuser -P mypasswd print -o <local filename> //depot/path/to/file`

2) Use a dedicated background user for the task, with an unlimited login expiration time (see [p4 group and the Timeout field](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/group.html#1040665)):

`p4 -u backgrounduser print -o <local filename> //depot/path/to/file`

A licensed "background user" designated for only performing automated tasks can be obtained at no further cost from Perforce Software. Try contacting Perforce support and ask them about this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried as you mentioned, but I got an error
"H:\>p4 -u asahu -p merijan007 print -o c:\temp.txt //dbx/Releases/SC/1.1.0.6/bui
ld_info.txt
Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        TCP connect to merijan007 failed.
        merijan007: service unknown.

Comment: @anirudh: You need to use upper-case "-P". "-p" is used for overriding P4PORT on the command-line; as you can see from the error message p4.exe tries to connect to the server "merijan007".

Comment: You can use p4 set P4USER=username and P4PASSWD=password so you don't need to put that stuff on the command line every time

Comment: @Fraser: Of course, but setting P4PASSWD is generally not a good idea from a security perspective.

Comment: Thanks Cwan, I got following response

H:\>p4 -u asahu -P merijan007 -o c:\temp.txt //dbx/Proj0590_ZonePRO64/Software/r
eleaseNotes.rtf
Perforce client error:
        p4 -h for usage.
        Invalid option: -o.

Comment: @anirudh: You are missing the actual "print" command, it should be: "p4 -u asahu -P merijan007 print -o c:\temp.txt //dbx/Proj0590_ZonePRO64/Software/releaseNotes.rtf"

Comment: There are some flaws in the answer: "background user" is actually called "operator users", but they can't use, e.g., the print command. Also, when the server is configured to ticket based authentication, then the -P option on the command line doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @stmoebius: See [this](http://www.perforce.com/support-services/request-background-user) form. I wasn't sure though about its applicability, hence the "contact support". Regarding ticket-based authentication: go for #2 or similar. I wouldn't call the answer "flawed" just because it doesn't cover every permutation of server security and command-line options.

Comment: You can also use the .p4config file configuration and run any script on the same directory... It worked for me defining all the variables P4CLIENT, P4USER, P4PASSWD, P4PORT...

Answer (score 2):

In a `bat` you can use the `p4.exe` commandline tool that comes with p4v and issue the `sync` command:

```
p4 sync myFileThatINeedToGetDaily.txt
```

Comment: Thank for the response, I tried as you suggested, but I got an error "Access for user 'sanirudh' has not been enabled by 'p4 protect'."

Answer (score 1):

Before Issuing Sync, make sure you have logged in and set the port and client view
p4 -u myuser -P mypasswd

p4 set P4PORT=server:nnnn

p4 sync file1.txt

Answer (score 0):

The command you need is [`p4 sync`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/sync.html).

Comment: When I issue any commands like sync, add, basically anything besides p4 sync, the command line freezes indefinitely.  My p4config, p4port is set and it never even shows an error.